# Where can I find the source code for the Customized Ubuntu Kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I have customized a kernel in one of my laptops (Ubuntu 8.04 ) and have the .deb files which I will be using further for my installation in other systems.

I will need to make changes to one of the modules of this customized kernel at code level. How can I retrieve the source kernel (I mean Linux Source here!) for this customized kernel,with which I can make changes to the modules and insert them in the kernel.

(I have installed customized kernel using the .deb file from another system runing on the same customized kernel)

Comment: so u will want to look for the src .deb file for the customized kernel, from another system

Comment: I want the source of the installed kernel in my current system (My current system is installed using the .deb file from another system)

Comment: Do you still have the original .deb files you used to install the custom kernel?  You should be able to do something like `dpkg -x kernel.deb ~/tmp/` (assuming `~/tmp` exists).

Comment: Thanks Michael!! Ya I do have the .deb's with me.. Is it possible to make changes to the extracted files (I actually want to do changes in source files of a particular module ,then perform a 'make' and insert .ko of the module into the running kernel!!) Will I be able to do it with these extracted files ?